# Browser trending on Google Analytics (data normalization)

Tags: google-analytics

We have seen the graphs that show the global browsers trending along time, in a scale from 0% to 100%

I'd like to get the same for my site using Google Analytics, but but in this case the scale is not a percentage, instead is the number of users ( i.e. 0 to 2000 ).

This would be ok if every day the same mount of users are accessing the site, but since there are natural spikes (due to week days or other events) the "browser trending" graph is following the same *bumps*, making it unreadable.

What I'm looking for is a way to normalize this data in a 0-100% range, but Google Analytics faqs were not useful.

Comment: So should I assume this is not possible?

Comment: I think @UVL wants the same as me, so hopefully this may bump the question up.  I also want to see a browser trending graph.  If I view Internet Explorer stats I can only see number of users.  I want to see a trend of the percentage who use IE6, 7, 8 and 9.  Once my users for IE6 go under 5% I am going to stop supporting the browser, so ideally I would also like to set this as a goal..

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible to create such a report using the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/#user_reports) in combination with the [UrlFetch features of Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp). With some programming you could create a Google Docs spreadsheet with normalized data.